# OS X Server ignoring static VPN IP request

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, l2tp

I've just enabled the VPN service on OS X Server, everything is working fine however we are facing one issue. All of our clients (about 30 iMac's) are connecting to the VPN with a static IP however OS X server returns another IP, this is a huge issue for us since we need static IP addresses on all these Mac's for managment.

The client settings (every mac will have an 192.168.103.XXX IP)
[image: Client settings]

This is what happens on the server when a client connects:

```
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : L2TP incoming call in progress from '10.108.224.12'...
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : L2TP received SCCRQ
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : L2TP sent SCCRP
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : L2TP received SCCCN
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : L2TP received ICRQ
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : L2TP sent ICRP
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : L2TP received ICCN
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : L2TP connection established.
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : using link 0
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : Using interface ppp0
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : Connect: ppp0 <--> socket[34:18]
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : CHAP peer authentication succeeded for vpn
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : DSAccessControl plugin: User 'vpn' authorized for access
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 10.108.65.16>]
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : sent [ACSCP ConfReq id=0x1]
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 192.168.103.2> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : ipcp: returning Configure-NAK
Thu Feb  6 13:57:58 2014 : sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <addr 192.168.103.1> <ms-dns1 10.241.20.20> <ms-dns3 10.241.20.21>]
```

As you can see in the last 3 rules, the IP 192.168.103.2 (which is entered manually on the client) is ignored and the client gets IP address 192.168.103.1 and the problem with this is that it changes every time.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what does `ifconfig -a` look like from the client machine when you are connected to the VPN? Specifically I am curious about the PPP virtual interface.

Comment: @DeanA.Vassallo It shows the following `ppp0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1280 inet 192.168.103.2 --> 10.108.65.16 netmask 0xffffff00`

Comment: is the address that you are attempting to manually assign within the L2TP IP range you specified in the L2TP configuration?

Comment: @DeanA.Vassallo Yes this is true, the server is configured to start with the `192.168.103.2` IP and to allow 50 clients over L2TP. I tried to set IP adres `192.168.103.2` on a client and `192.168.103.3` on another client but this is ignored.